# Core Image Kernel Language API deprecated Warning Issue

Tags: swift, core-image

I am getting warning

**'init(source:)' was deprecated in iOS 12.0: Core Image Kernel Language API deprecated. (Define CI_SILENCE_GL_DEPRECATION to silence these warnings)**

for following code and could not find a solution except silencing the warning.

```
func createCustomKernel() -> CIColorKernel {
    let kernelString =  "kernel vec4 chromaKey(__sample s, __color c, float threshold){\n" +
        "vec4 diff = s.rgba - c;\n" +
        "float distance = length( diff );\n" +
        "float alpha =  compare( distance - threshold , 0.0, 1.0 );\n" +
       "return vec4(s.rgb, alpha );\n" +
    "}"
    return CIColorKernel(source: kernelString)!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The use of the CI Kernel Language for writing Core Image kernels is deprecated for a while now. Instead, CI kernels should be written in Metal.

You can check out [this WWDC talk](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc20/10021) on how this is done.